# Swagger definition errors

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, enunciate

Trying to use Swagger on my JAX-RS application with `enunciate` Maven plugin.

The generated JSON definition works well.

But when I try to validate it online with Swagger Editor, the converted YAML file has some weird errors.

For example:
Definition:

```
 parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          type: file
          description: 'Bla bla'
      responses:
        '201':
```

ERROR:
`Parameters with "type: file" must have "in: formData"`

JAX-RS Code:

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/validatedata")
public Response validate(ValidateDataFromInput validateDataFromInput) throws CustomException {
    return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).entity(validationActionService.getDataFromInput(validateDataFromInput.getConsumerInput(),
        validateDataFromInput.getValidateInput(), null)).build();
}
```

I am using: `swagger-core-1.5.21` and `enunciate-maven-plugin-2.11.1`. 
Not sure which is wrong here.

Comment: Please post the source code of your controller.

Comment: Controller? Do you mean the Java code for Rest endpoint?

Comment: Yes, the Java code

Comment: Added code to the post. Any thoughts?